# Logstash input plugin for Instagram Streaming API

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, instagram-api

I want to read events from the Instagram. I was wondering if I can do it using Logstash similar to reading events from Twitter using Twitter input plugin, but there is no input plugin for Instagram. Is there any other way to collect Instagram data using Logstash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram [has an API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) so you can definitely attempt something with the [`http_poller`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html) plugin.

Something like this:

```
input {
   http_poller {
      urls => {
         search => {
            method => get
            url => "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN"
         }
      }
      request_timeout => 60
      interval => 60
      codec => "json"
   }
}
output {
   stdout {
       codec => rubydebug
   }
}
```

Comment: I will try this, Thank you so much Val!

Answer (score 0):

What's your mean of Instagram events?

If you want to store your Insta media, write a plugin for your browser or write a crawler and send media to elasticsearch

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Thank you for your suggestion. I already have a plugin written for this task but, use of Logstash plugin will make things much more simple and manageable.