# How to consume data in elasticsearch from a HTTP/REST API call

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on a project where I need to create a Kibana dashboard with devops metrics.
We have multiple toolsets being used(Bitbucket, TeamCity, SonarQube, Nexus, Nolio).
The intention of the dashboard is to show a highlevel snapshot of the project/application health. This will include some details such as; change lead time, deployment frequency, mean time to recovery, change failure rate, Code quality, number of commits, etc

My question is this; all the above tool sets have a RESTful API exposed(or http/s for that matter), hence how do I consume these data returned by the API calls from the devops tools (or the UI page of these tools) and them inset them into elasticsearch for it to be later used by Kibana.

Installing logstash or beats on the servers where these devops services are running is not an option as this is a centralized for the organization and having a third party software installed here will need a lot of hopping around for approvals and processes.

Please let me know if anymore information is required from myside.

Comment: Using Logstash's [`http_poller` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html) gives you the flexibility to regularly poll those HTTP endpoint from a central location where Logstash is installed and then stream the results to Elasticsearch. See an example usage here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864201/logstash-input-plugin-for-instagram-streaming-api/38864866#38864866

Comment: Thanks @Val, I will give it a try. Can we post the messages directly to the ElasticSearch ingest nodes bypassing logstash? Your solution definitely is doable i am just thinking out loud for any other options to try

Comment: If you don't want to use Logstash which tool is going to call your endpoints and forward the results to the ES ingest nodes?

Comment: Ok, I get it now. What about beats(file beats?) , as they have a smaller footprint than logstash

Comment: Beats can only be installed on the hosts they are fetching data from, except heartbeat, but its job is merely to ping remote hosts, not really to fetch HTTP data from them.

Comment: ok, i have enough info to start. i will keep posted with the output

Comment: @baggi how did it go?

Comment: @fix, I did not proceed much on this. We moved over to an inhouse .NET app which is now doing this job. Happy to hear how are you implementing this